# Excel formula to calculate the total time spent on various tasks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need a formula to calculate the total time spent on various tasks but I want the total splitting across the relevant interval each day.

For example, column A has the start time and column B has the end time.

Columns C & D just have the intervals by 30mins ranging from 07:00-23:00.

Within column E, I need a formula that will calculate time spent of a task from 09:07-10:56 but for the relevant 30 minute interval to populate i.e. 09:00-09:30 would be 23 minutes, 09:30-10:00 would be 30 mins etc.

I have thousands of tasks so when I add a new one, I'd like a cumulative total as I go on.

Comment: You've not made sense, I'm afraid. There are thirty-two 30 minute intervals between 07:00 and 23:00, so you need thirty-two columns to have a column for each interval, not two.

Comment: Mock up the desired result in your spreadsheet. Enter the numbers manually. Take a screenshot. Upload that to a free file sharing site, since you cannot yet post images. Post the link here.

Comment: See if this is right: You have thousands of rows of tasks, each with a start time in col A and end time in col B.  You have 32 time increments, each on a row with increment start time in col C and end time in col D.  In col E, you want to calculate the task times split across the relevant time increments, so col E will have 32 rows.  Are you just looking for a workload distribution by time interval?  You want to total all of the task time breakdowns row by row in col E, so the 1st row has the total of all tasks that occurred between 07:00 and 07:30?

Comment: Yes spot on.  The first row within column E would give me the total time spent on all the tasks within columns A and B between 07:00-07:30.

Comment: And you want this whole thing to automatically include any new tasks you add so you don't need to manually modify formula ranges for each new task?

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted. Also, a screen shot would be nice to make it really clear what you're trying to ask, even if you just show how the data currently looks. Did you try anything yourself, any Excel formula or VBa?

Comment: Yes please.  Dave - I'll try upload what i'm talking about although fixer explains it above.

Comment: Dan, to get you started, I can see three approaches.  VBA is probably the simplest.  You could also do it with simple formulas if you build a table where the rows are your data and 32 columns are the time increments.  Each table cell calculates a col E value for one task and one time interval and a col E cell contains a column total from the table.  You could pre-populate the table with an arbitrarily large number of rows that get used as you add data.  You also might be able to do this with array formulas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to divide a time period into equal time periods](http://superuser.com/q/784389/150988).

Answer (score 1):

I *really* wish I could attach files
If anybody has a solution for that, let me know
I have a solution for you. First, some setup:

---

You can setup this same thing with dynamic named ranges and using those in your formulas but I like tables so I used those.
I created a table in columns A:B called tblTimeLog
It has two fields: Start, Stop
This is where you input all your start and stop work times as needed

I created a second table in columns D:G called tblTimeSummary
It has 4 fields: Interval Stare, Interval Stop, Interval, Total Time
Interval Start & Stop are conveniences
You *could* do everything with a single text field showing the time span but the formulas are much simpler if you split it out
These two will hold time ranges like 07:00 and 07:30, 07:30 and 08:00, etc.
I typed these in by hand and autofill
Interval simply combines the two for the sake of presentation so you get things like "07:00 - 07:30", "07:30 - 08:00", etc.
I used a formula here: `=TEXT([@[Interval Start]],"HH:mm") & " - " & TEXT([@[Interval Stop]],"HH:mm")`
Total Time is where it will calculate how much work was done in that interval.

---

Here's the big formula for Total Time:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((tblTimeLog[Start]<=[@[Interval Stop]])*(tblTimeLog[Stop]>[@[Interval Start]])*(IF([@[Interval Stop]]<=tblTimeLog[Stop],[@[Interval Stop]],tblTimeLog[Stop])-IF([@[Interval Start]]>tblTimeLog[Start],[@[Interval Start]],tblTimeLog[Start])))*24*60
```

Let's break that down
`SUMPRODUCT` will create arrays, multiply each row together, then sum those rows
It's important to know that this will treat `TRUE` as 1 and `FALSE` as 0

The first array is `(tblTimeLog[Start]<=[@[Interval Stop]])`
That finds all the log entries that started before the end of this interval

The second array is the opposite idea `(tblTimeLog[Stop]>[@[Interval Start]])`
It finds all the log entries that ended after the start of this interval
Together, they find all the log entries that have some amount of time within the interval

`(IF([@[Interval Stop]]<=tblTimeLog[Stop],[@[Interval Stop]],tblTimeLog[Stop])`
This array selects either the end of the interval or the end of the activity, whichever came *first*

`IF([@[Interval Start]]>tblTimeLog[Start],[@[Interval Start]],tblTimeLog[Start])`
This array selects either the start of the interval or the start of the activity, whichever came *last*

The difference between the last two arrays gives you how much time of each log entry was spent in this particular interval.

`*24*60` this bit at the end just turns the time value in days into a value in minutes

---

Let's summarize with some pseudo-code:
`=Sum((If the log entry is in this interval)*(How much time was spent in this interval))`
The first array will be 1 or 0 and the second will be some time value
Multiplying them together gives an array of 0 and time values
Summing that gives you the total logged time in that interval